# GWT Label format Object String

Tags: json, apache, gwt

I have an String representation of an object obtained from `reflectionToString` method (http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/ToStringBuilder.html#reflectionToString%28java.lang.Object%29) and I need to put it into a GWT `Label`. But this string could be very long and I wanted to display it in a nice format, ideally in json format.

Anyone has any suggestions on how to format it?

Comment: Eclipse can generate toString methods easily : Source > Generate toString. Then replace all comas and = to reformat the string in json

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like http://highlightjs.org/ to format the raw text/code in a vaguely human readable way? Calling JS from GWT is pretty easy.